# Using countif in Oracle sql to calculate for each row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Can i know is there any sql statment like in `Excel` `countif` to count high, medium and low which is based on condition.

For instance, the table below shows on using countif in high we can see High how much, low how much and medium how much for each row

```
ID   Name     Value1     Value2     Value3    ValueN   High   Medium  Low
---  -------  ---------  ---------  --------  -------  -----  ------  ------
1    A        High       High       Low       Medium   2      1       1 
2    AB       Low        Medium     Low       High     1      1       2
3    ABC      High       Low        Low       High     2      0       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use first `UNPIVOT` data and then do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ID, Name,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'High' THEN 1 END)   AS High,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Medium' THEN 1 END) AS Medium,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Low' THEN 1 END)    AS Low
FROM tab
UNPIVOT( val FOR col_name IN (Value1, Value2, Value3, ValueN)) unpvt
GROUP BY ID, Name
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/444269)**</kbd>

To handle more column just add them to:

```
val FOR col_name IN (Value1, Value2, Value3, ValueN)
```

---

And final query with all columns from original tab:

```
SELECT t.*, sub.High, sub.Medium, sub.Low
FROM tab t
JOIN (SELECT ID, Name, 
         COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'High' THEN 1 END)   AS High,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Medium' THEN 1 END) AS Medium,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Low' THEN 1 END)    AS Low
      FROM tab
      UNPIVOT( val FOR col_name IN (Value1, Value2, Value3, ValueN)) unpvt
      GROUP BY ID, Name) sub
  ON t.ID = sub.ID
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/444278)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦══════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦══════╦════════╦═════╗
║ ID ║ Name ║ Value1 ║ Value2 ║ Value3 ║ ValueN ║ High ║ Medium ║ Low ║
╠════╬══════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬══════╬════════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ A    ║ High   ║ High   ║ Low    ║ Medium ║    2 ║      1 ║   1 ║
║  2 ║ AB   ║ Low    ║ Medium ║ Low    ║ High   ║    1 ║      1 ║   2 ║
║  3 ║ ABC  ║ High   ║ Low    ║ Low    ║ High   ║    2 ║      0 ║   2 ║
╚════╩══════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩══════╩════════╩═════╝
```

Comment: thanks sir, sir can i know is there like like can we jsut put col_name IN (*) as it will be easier

Comment: thanks this is good but can i know like under col_name can is there a way to specify like col)name  IN (*)

Comment: @Jayam Probably yes using metadata and dynamic-SQL. But it will be much longer, less readable and harder to maintain. Anyway I have no access to Oracle instance so I could not help with that.

Comment: k no prob sir.. u gave me the idea.. i will research on it.. and gain further knoweldge and implement it..